# Show and Hide a div upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

Basically, I have an About Me page which will show a summary of the about section, under this will be a button which once clicked I want it to hide the summary part and display the detailed DIV. I currently have the following code which only toggles the detailed section and does not hide the summary section. Thanks:

HTML:

```
<div class="row" class="unhidden" id="about_basic">
    <!-- Summary Content Here -->
</div>

<a href="javascript:unhide('about_detailed');" class="btn-large">View Detail</a>
<!-- The Javascript in the href tag needs to unhide the about_detailed section (As it does here) but THEN hide the about_basic section. -->

<div id="about_detailed" class="hidden">
    <!-- Detailed Content Here -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
  }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
.unhidden { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is considered poor form to write javascript "inline" (that is, as an attribute of an HTML element). It works, but is difficult to maintain.

Also, jQuery handles this so nicely... *There is no need for the unhide function, OR for the hidden/unhidden css classes*

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3mcrm/)</kbd>

**jQuery:**

```
$('.btn-large').click(function() {
    $('#about_basic').toggle();
    $('#about_detailed').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('about_detailed');" 
   class="btn-large">
     View Detail
</a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('about_detailed');unhide('about_basic')" 
   class="btn-large">
     View Detail
</a>
```

will toggle the `about_basic` section together with the `about_detailed` section.